# how to parse csv file in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have the following code to read from a csv file, yet I am confused at certain points.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "rU") as csvfile:
            f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            # f.next() #if an input file a headed
            for row in f: params.append(row)

        for i in xrange(nproc, 0, -1):
            load.append(params[::i])
            del params[::i]
```

For my understanding, params is a list in which each element is a row of the input csv file. Then, what is the meaning of params[::i] then? Does it mean the third column of the input csv file?

Comment: It means _"every **i**th row"_ so if `i` is 3, every third **row** (not column); since as you correctly understood param is a list where each element is a row of the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` in `params[::i]` is called the [*stride*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slicings#slicings) of the slice. Since the `::` part means the whole sequence, it has the effect of selecting every `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the sequence.

To see the effect of this, assume that `params` is a row of data from the csv file that has sequential letters of the alphabet in each column. In the code below I made it a string, which is a sequence of characters, only to make the output more readable.

```
params = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in xrange(3, 0, -1):
    print('for i: {}, params[::i] --> {}'.format(i, params[::i]))
```

Output:

```
for i: 3, params[::i] --> adgjmpsvy
for i: 2, params[::i] --> acegikmoqsuwy
for i: 1, params[::i] --> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The effect of the `del params[::i]` is best illustrated with another code snippet. In a nutshell it removes every `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the sequence. In the code below the sequence is again converted to a string for readability of the output.

```
params = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

for i in xrange(3, 0, -1):
    temp = params[:]  # make copy to avoid changing it every iteration
    del temp[::i]
    print('for i: {}, del params[::i] --> {}'.format(i, ''.join(temp)))
```

Output:

```
for i: 3, del params[::i] --> bcefhiklnoqrtuwxz
for i: 2, del params[::i] --> bdfhjlnprtvxz
for i: 1, del params[::i] -->
```

Comment: Thanks very much. One more question: here nproc is the number of processors, load is an empty list. So, what is the meaning of load.append(params[: : i ]) ?

Comment: The `load.append(params[::i])` is appending the elements in the sequence defined by the `params[::i]` slice to the end of the `load` list, right before deleting them from `params` itself in the next statement.